# Asking about how a dish tastes

Tags: word-choice

Suppose there's a mom who has made a meal for her guests, and she has bring the meal to the table and let her guests to try the meal, what would she ask with?

> Sentence A: Does it taste good?
>
> Sentence B: Is it tasty?

Comment: "How is it?" or "How does it taste?"

Comment: You should really wait before awarding the green tick, people might contribute with other ideas. But thank you all the same!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I have cooked for my partner, or my son with his girlfriend, I'll often ask:

- Is it any good?
- Is it OK?
- Do you like it?

They are my closest family and I see them so often it's all right, and acceptable to ask for confirmation.

If however, I have cooked a meal for some guests I would not want to embarrass or prompt them by asking if they find the food *tasty* or *delicious*. Instead people are kind enough to remark that the meal is *really good*; or *this is sooo good*; or *it's perfect*. But if no one asks for seconds, it's a sure sign sign that something went wrong in the kitchen!

The situation changes when I find myself in a restaurant, in that case I might ask my partner if his dish is tasty because I am curious. He would not risk hurting my feelings if he said the dish was *"bland"* or *"Nothing to write home about."*

- Is it tasty?
- What's it like?
- It looks absolutely delicious! Is it?

Comment: +1 esp. for "Do you like it?" In the restaurant, another way to ask this question is, "Does that taste as good as it looks?"